# Как сортировать элементы из базы данных в алфавитном порядке в Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Использовал `Item.order(:name)`. Элементы сортируются таким образом: "item 14", "item 15", "item 16", "item 3", "item 4"

Но надо сделать вот так: "item 3", "item 4", "item 14", "item 15", "item 16"

Comment: При сортировке строк сравнение символов идет слева направо, при сравнении чисел - права налево. У вас строка, но сортировать вы хотите ее как число, поэтому следует извлечь число: (1) отдельный столбец, (2) выражение средствами СУБД и отсортировать по нему. В любом случае для полного ответа на ваш вопрос, потребуется еще название базы данных, так как диалекты SQL довольно сильно отличаются.

Comment: У вас заголовок вопроса противоречит телу вопроса. Вам действительно выдало алфавитный порядок. Вы же хотите **не** алфавитный.

Comment: Использую postgresql

Comment: @SemyonKotov может [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557307/2223918) найдете ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
Item.order("left(name, 1), substring(name, '\\d+')::int NULLS FIRST, name").pluck(:name)
```

В свое время мне помогло [это решение](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/52569/order-by-alphabet-and-then-by-numbers/52626#52626).